# Include related custom fields from one post type in another post type's JSON feed

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, plugin-json-api, pods-framework

I have a custom post type called Offers, and in this post type is a custom field called Store, which is a relationship field type to another custom post type Stores.

This has been created using the Pods framework.

I'm using the JSON API plugin to get a feed of Offers, and you can include custom fields via the URL, as such:

```
/feed/?post_type=offer&json=get_recent_posts&custom_fields=store
```

This naturally only returns the ID of the Store post though.

How can I return not only the Post Title of the Store, but a further custom field from the Store post itself?